# I'm trying to make an iWidget for my jailbroken iPhone. I'm having trouble with the HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, ios, plist

//Below is the Widget.html file. This is the file that i need help with mainly. This part doesn't work like I expected it to. The widget itself works except it wont show the sites. I'm trying to make it to where it shows a Reddit slideshow where the user can select which subreddit they want to view and an option of how to view it(top, hot, rising, controversial). The complete code has 10 subreddits to choose from so far; I cut off eight to shorten the post. When you use it, you can successfully choose a subreddit and option, but when you hit "Add," it just makes a box, so I know my .plist files work. I'm just unsure of how to get this .html file to function properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var inst_a = new Array(); //subreddit selection
        var inst_b = new Array(); //options

        //gaming
        //option1
        inst_a[1] + inst_b[11] = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/top/?t=all" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option2
        inst_a[1] + inst_b[12]  = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option3
        inst_a[1] + inst_b[13]  = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/rising" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option4
        inst_a[1] + inst_b[14]  = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/controversial/?t=all" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //news
        //option1
        inst_a[2] + inst_b[11] = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/news/top/?t=all" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option2
        inst_a[2] + inst_b[12] = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/news" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option3
        inst_a[2] + inst_b[13] = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/news/rising" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
        //option4
        inst_a[2] + inst_b[14] = '<iframe src="http://www.redditp.com/r/news/controversial/?t=all" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';


        $('#wrapper').html(inst_a[feed] + inst_b[feed]);

        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

// Below is the Options.plist that is used for the input from the user. The first set of dict tags is to select the subreddit.  The last set is to select the subreddit options(hot,rising,etc.).

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>feed</string>
      <key>type</key>
      <string>select</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Feed</string>
      <key>default</key>
      <string>News</string>
      <key>options</key>
       <dict>
         <key>News</key>
         <string>1</string>
         <key>Gaming</key>
         <string>2</string>
       </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>vMode</string>
      <key>type</key>
      <string>select</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>View Options</string>
      <key>default</key>
      <string>Hot</string>
      <key>options</key>
      <dict>
         <key>Top</key>
         <string>11</string>
         <key>Hot</key>
         <string>12</string>
         <key>Rising</key>
         <string>13</string>
         <key>Controversial</key>
         <string>14</string>
       </dict>
     </dict>    
  </array>
</plist>
```

Comment: What do you expect something like `inst_a[x] + inst_b[y] = ""` to do anyways? You're trying to assign an expression (in this case, a literal string) to an expression which is not possible. Also, you never configure those arrays after they're created (unless you omitted it) so you're adding `undefined` to `undefined`.

Comment: The inst_a and inst_b are from the array. It's made to be like choosing settings. If , for say, they chose News and the option Rising, the code would say he chose inst_a[1] and inst_b[13] and that that would meet a condition and the user would be shown that website.

Comment: That's what you want to do. But that is not what your doing. You also never load the array with any values.

Comment: I had a previous version of this that worked just fine. It only had the subreddits to choose from so there was only one array.  Now I'm trying to add another array as seen above and I don't know how.  I was hoping it would be as simple as adding two integers, but I'm wrong.

Comment: would this work:    if ((inst_a[i] === inst_a[1]) && (inst_b[i] === inst_b[1]))   And I would then tell it to go to the website?

Comment: That looks better, but what is `i` going to be?

Comment: It would be the value of the string that the user selects.

Comment: How would I test to find i?  Would a for loop work? for  (int i = 0; i<inst_a.Length;i++)

Comment: I provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this all wrong and most likely due to a lack of 
experience writing code. Before I go on into a possible solution for you I'd 
highly recommend that you study more about Javascript and general programming 
knowledge before moving forward with your next project.

I'm going to step you through solving this problem (at least in the method I'd 
recommend) instead of just telling you what will "solve" your problem. So step 
one is examing that `<iframe>` string you're building. Do you see anything 
that is the same between all of them?

```
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>
```

I've removed the URLs to make it more clear the piont here, and as you can see
they're all exactly the same line. This is a prime chance to clean up this
repetitive code. and make it a function.

```
var buildIframeCode = function(url) {
  return '<iframe src="' + url + '" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height: 480px" ></iframe>';
};
```

That makes that easier, now lets check out the URLs:

```
http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/top/?t=all
http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming
http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/rising
http://www.redditp.com/r/gaming/controversial/?t=all
http://www.redditp.com/r/news/top/?t=all
http://www.redditp.com/r/news
http://www.redditp.com/r/news/rising
http://www.redditp.com/r/news/controversial/?t=all
```

Well, they all share the same base, so this is again a prime chance to reuse
that. The URL takes to parameters here, the subreddit and the sort here so 
we'll need to take two arguments:

```
var buildRedditUrl = function(subreddit, sort) {
  return "http://www.redditp.com/r/" + subreddit + sort;
};
```

Now we've got those two setup, anytime an option changes I can just easily do:

```
buildIframeCode(buildRedditUrl(selectedSubreddit, selectedSort));
```

And those options don't need number, we can use strings now like:

```
var reddits = {
  "Gaming": "gaming",
  "News": "news"
};

var sorts = {
  "Top": "/top/?t=all",
  "Hot": "",
  "Rising": "/rising",
  "Controversial": "/controversial/?t=all"
};
```

You can, of course, load those from a plist file if that is the method you'd 
wish to take. And now you're all set to move forward.

To integrate with your example:

```
$("#wrapper").html(buildIframeCode(buildRedditUrl(reddits[selectedReddit], sort[selectedSort])));
```

Comment: I didn't know it could be so simple. You are right when you said I need to learn more JavaScript. I'm just beginning to learn this language. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, it's good to know what options you have to take before you try to take them. Good luck on the rest of this project!

Comment: One last question: Would would i need to change this to   $('#wrapper').html(inst_a[feed] + inst_b[feed]);  ?

Comment: That is where I would insert your new `iframe` code.

Comment: How would I use this with the .plist file?  When I select an option now, the program doesn't know how to get to the html file.

Comment: I don't know anything specifically about your target platform. I do standard iOS applications and have done some JavaScript. Best answer I give to that is find out how to read a plots file using the iWidget API.

Comment: Is there a way to use a var x = new Array() system with what you've made?

Comment: Instead of an array I created an object in my examples. Your use of an array in this program is flawed so I don't recommend it. If you look at the end of my answer is an example to read from the objects based on user input values. You'll have to do the work to get those input values though.